# Hadoop Cassandra wide rows in CqlInputFormat

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am writing a hadoop job that uses Cassandra (v2.0.11) as its input and output.

In my hadoop job I define input column family:

```
ConfigHelper.setInputColumnFamily(job.getConfiguration(), KEYSPACE, INPUT_COLUMN_FAMILY, WIDE_ROWS);
```

where `WIDE_ROWS=true`. I also set `CqlInputFormat` as a reading class:

```
job.setInputFormatClass(CqlInputFormat.class);
```

`CqlInputFormat` uses `CqlRecordReader` where it's written ([link](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.0.13/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/hadoop/cql3/CqlRecordReader.java)):

```
// Because the old Hadoop API wants us to write to the key and value
// and the new asks for them, we need to copy the output of the new API
// to the old. Thus, expect a small performance hit.
// And obviously this wouldn't work for wide rows. But since ColumnFamilyInputFormat
// and ColumnFamilyRecordReader don't support them, it should be fine for now.
public boolean next(Long key, Row value) throws IOException
{
    if (nextKeyValue())
    {
        ((WrappedRow)value).setRow(getCurrentValue());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I quite do not understand it... When i check `ColumnFamilyRecordReader` code ([link](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.0.13/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/hadoop/ColumnFamilyRecordReader.java)) it seems that is uses wide rows...
Does `CqlInputFormat` really support wide rows? Could you explain it?

Comment: I also noticed that "wide row" property from `ConfigHelper` class is only accessed in `ColumnFamilyRecordReader`, see: [here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/search?utf8=✓&q=getInputIsWide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated it and realized that CQL "transposes" wide rows so that each column is fed to map function separately (`CqlInputFormat` runs CQL queries to get data from cassandra node).

This approach will not cause OOM exception when dealing with very wide rows because `CqlInputFormat` uses paging mechanism available in CQL. It takes only `CqlConfigHelper.getInputCQLPageRowSize` columns per page.

Unfortunatelly in my case it is not efficient because I would like to perform a "group by" operation on each row key to count columns. And incrementing a counter in a loop of sereveral thousands of columns is slower than just taking `columns.size()` (if there would be such possibility).

More to read about it:
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3-for-cassandra-experts
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3264